# Double pointing relationship? Relationship from relationship?

Tags: neo4j

How do you model when a node does something to another node (relationship) but also in an event? What's the best solution?

For example: PLayerA-[PASSED]->PlayerB-[IN]->GameA

You can't query that unless GameA is the only game you've got.
What would make sense for me is to have the IN relationship going from the PASSED relationship. Like this:

[image: Made up relationship]

I big part of me tells me I don't know this cause I don't understand the graph modelling yet. How would you model this the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the correct way to model that is by extracting the Passed relationship into a Node - creating a [HyperEdge](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypher-cookbook-hyperedges.html). The new Pass Node will now have relationships to the source and target players as well as the game in which the pass occurred. There is a football related example of this by Mark Needham on [DZone](http://java.dzone.com/articles/neo4j-modeling-hyper-edges).

Your query would end up looking more like:

```
MATCH (p:Player{name:'Player A'})-[:PASSED]->(po:PassObject)-[:RECEIVED]->(r:Player{name:'Player B'})
RETURN COUNT(po)
```

For all passes ever between the two players, or:

```
MATCH (p:Player{name:'Player A'})-[:PASSED]->(po:PassObject)-[:RECEIVED]->(r:Player{name:'Player B'})
MATCH (po)-[:IN_GAME]->(g:Game)
WHERE g.fixture = "WhateverYouUseToIdentifyYourGames"
RETURN COUNT(po)
```

For passes in a single game.

Comment: HyperEdge seem to be exactly what it is! Thank you!